# What is the best approach to update child table when updating parent table?

Tags: c#, .net-core, repository-pattern, ef-core-3.0

Net core Ef Core. I have two tables, Schema looks like below.

```
 Student table - StudentId Name Class, IsActive 
 Address Table - AddressId, City, Country, IsActive, StudentId
```

Idea is when I update Student IsActive Field as False, I also want to update corresponding Address table IsActive also false.

The approach what I thought is, After updating Student table, create one more method which will update address table based on student id. For example,

```
UpdateStudent(int studentid)
{
     //update student
     //If success call method update AddressUpdate(int studentid)
}
AddressUpdate(int studentid)
{
    //update address table
}
```

I am using Generic repository pattern as below.

```
public void Update(T entity)
{
    this.dbSet.Attach(entity);
    this.dbContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
}
```

Can someone tell me is there any other best way to handle this? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: This can be done by triggers in sql. But why have two columns if they should allways have the same value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do different.
When you get the student details from the database you have to get the address details as well (just one call using Include)

You can set both fields as false and just execute one SaveChanges to update it.
var stu
student.isActive = false;
student.address.isActive = false;

ctx.SaveChanges();

Comment: Thanks yeah looks best can you share some examples?

Comment: Also If address is list, for example its one to many relationships then how we can handle this?

Comment: Something like that:
static void DeleteUser(int studentId)
        {
            //Get value
            var student = this.dbContext.Students.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == studentId, i => i.Include(Address));
            student.isActive = false; 
            student.address.isActive = false;

            this.dbContext.SaveChanges();
        }